# custom sort of Real numbers in spotfire

Tags: sorting, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

Could anyone help me on how to custom sort on real numbers in spotfire 7.11.

This is my data before sorting (I can implement this in excel but not in spotfire):

```
A   B   C
1   3   1
2   4   2
3   2   3
4   1   4
5   4   5
6   5   6
7   6   7
6   7   8
8   1   9
9   0   10
```

This is the custom sorting condition:

[image]

This is the data after custom sorting.

```
A   B   C
6   7   8
7   6   7
6   5   6
5   4   5
2   4   2
1   3   1
3   2   3
8   1   9
4   1   4
9   0   10
```

I tried adding the columns A and B, creating a new calculated column and sort the column in descending order. But, it's wrong approach.

I tried using this formula - (5 * [A]) + (10 * [B]) and calculate a new column and then sort them using descending order. But, I think it's wrong approach.

Can anyone help me to implement this with spotfire ? I tried checking the custom sort in edit -> Column Properties but I couldn't find this function in spotfire.

Comment: The data you show after custom sorting seems correctly sorted first by B then by A. Can you post a screenshot of your desired result?

Comment: Yes. First sorting by B and then by A. That is correct. The desired result is the second table @GaiaPaolini

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I sorted the first column to be sorted and then I used SHIFT + CTRL + clicked the second column to be sorted. It works for me !